# What does GCC use instead of GEP?

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-construction, llvm

Of the two best-known C compilers, LLVM handles address calculation of elements of compound objects with the somewhat notorious `getelementptr` instruction, which is perhaps most readably discussed in https://blog.yossarian.net/2020/09/19/LLVMs-getelementptr-by-example

But basically the most conspicuous feature of GEP, as far as I can see, is that it is unique among LLVM instructions in putting an arbitrarily long sequence of calculations into one instruction. I haven't been able to find any explanation of why it was decided to do this instead of breaking it up into several LEA instructions each performing a single calculation.

What does GCC use instead?

Godbolt doesn't seem to provide IR output for GCC, so I took an example from the above page:

```
typedef struct foo {
  struct {
    long field1;
    struct {
      long field2;
      long field3;
      union {
        long field4;
        char field5[32];
      } quux;
      long field6;
      long field7;
    } baz;
    long field8;
  } bar;
} foo;

foo chunky;

char take_field(void) {
  return chunky.bar.baz.quux.field5[17];
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -fdump-tree-all a.c` and got, among other things, `a.c.020t.ssa` with the following contents:

```
;; Function take_field (take_field, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=1810, cgraph_uid=0, symbol_order=1)

take_field ()
{
  char D.1813;
  char _2;

  <bb 2> [0.00%]:
  _2 = chunky.bar.baz.quux.field5[17];

<L0> [0.00%]:
  return _2;

}
```

Now, I wouldn't have been surprised to see it doing the same thing as LLVM.

I also wouldn't have been surprised to see it breaking up the big address calculation into a sequence of smaller calculations.

But from what I can see, what it actually does is just squashes all the calculations together into a single 'add 17'.

Is this how GCC handles address calculations in general? If so... I sort of want to ask why it does this, but I suppose the real question would be the other way around: if that suffices, then other things equal, simpler is clearly better, so if that suffices, why does LLVM use the more complex form that places an arbitrarily long sequence of calculations in one instruction? Is there a disadvantage in squashing it into a single number? Or if there is a disadvantage, then why does GCC do that?

Comment: GCC seems to perform constant-folding optimization on offsets at an earlier stage, and vectorizing of address calculations at a later one.

Comment: This question is mostly about a matter of opinion, so it may be closed. But I'll give you something to help you form your own opinion. LLVM tries to make it easy to write custom passes and GCC doesn't. Write a custom pass that identifies all writes to a given struct field. The struct should be this: `%foo = type <{ i1, i7, i32, i512 }>`, that is, a packed struct with four integer fields, each of a different width. Do this for both LLVM and GCC, and see what you think about GEP vs. what GCC does.

Comment: Worth considering: if you assume all input languages have structured types whose field offsets are determined once, relatively early, you can easily fold offset calculations together. But if you assume input language have structured types whose fields are adjustable—e.g., the compiler can decide at link time which fields go where, or even dis-aggregate the structures to put particular fields in separate arrays for cache purposes—you don't want to do this folding early; you want to defer it until the very end.

Comment: Whether that's the LLVM motivation, or there's some other, I don't know, but it's a sort of obvious thing once you view it that way.